# How to handle ParseError when evaluating exponents (powers) in Julia

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

I use Julia version 1.10.0. When evaluating power expressions such as `2^3`, in REPL, Pluto or VScode, the exponent change immediately into a superscript and then get a ParseError with the information that the exponent (in this case, the number 3) is an unknown unicode character. I am new to Julia and I do not see how to handle this error. This happens to any expression containing a mathematical operation with a power.

```
julia> 2³
ERROR: ParseError:
# Error @ REPL[1]:1:2
2³
# unknown unicode character '3'
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ none:1
julia>
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of text replacement feature enabled on your computer? This definitely isn't supposed to happen automatically.

Comment: The exponent should not change as you should type `\^3<TAB>` in order for that to happen. `3` and `³` are simply different Unicode characters and it is a special feature of editor that enables the `\^3<TAB>` sequence.

Comment: @BallpointBen: I have installed Julia on Ubuntu and Ubuntu is installed on Oracle VirtualBox version 7.0. The only Julia packages I installed using "add" command are Pluto and LaTexStrings. These packages are installed globally (i.e. on the default virtual environmet @1.10). I also used "using CommonMark" in one of my tests in Pluto: got info that CommonMark was going to be installed in the Pluto notebook.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel: I agree with you. Typing ^3 should not change immediately into superscript 3.

Comment: It seems that it is an issue of Ubuntu and Keyboard. I will check if the proposed solution is working for me.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/978505/how-to-prevent-automatic-superscript-when-typing-caret-sign-and-a-number

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `Ubuntu` and the `Keyboard`. The answer is to press the hat (caret) key twice in order to obtain the `^` effect. This answer is from https://askubuntu.com/questions/56560/what-exactly-is-meant-by-eliminate-dead-keys